# Como obter somente determinadas tags de um XML

Tags: python, python-3.x, xml

Preciso ler um XML e printar somente algumas linhas que possuem a mesma tag. Consegui carregar o XML, e fiz um laço para percorrê-lo e printar as tags e os atributos subsequentes:

```
import xml.etree.ElementTree as ET
import requests

tree = ET.parse('pt_cadbai.xml')
root = tree.getroot()

for row in root:
    print(row.tag, row.attrib)
```

Porém, só está sendo printado `METADATA {}` e `ROWDATA {}`.

Esse é o XML:

```xml
<?xml version="1.0" standalone="yes"?>
<DATAPACKET Version="2.0">
    <METADATA>
        <FIELDS>
            <FIELD attrname="CODIGO_BAI" fieldtype="i4" required="true">
                <PARAM Name="PROVFLAGS" Value="7" Type="i4" Roundtrip="True" />
            </FIELD>
            <FIELD attrname="EMPRESA_BAI" fieldtype="i4" required="true" />
            <FIELD attrname="DESCRICAO_BAI" fieldtype="string" WIDTH="60" />
            <FIELD attrname="CODIGO_TCE_BAI" fieldtype="i4" />
            <FIELD attrname="CHK_DESM_BAI" fieldtype="string" WIDTH="1" />
        </FIELDS>
        <PARAMS DEFAULT_ORDER="1" PRIMARY_KEY="1" LCID="0" />
    </METADATA>
    <ROWDATA>
        <ROW CODIGO_BAI="0" EMPRESA_BAI="2" DESCRICAO_BAI="Desconhecido" CHK_DESM_BAI="N" />
        <ROW CODIGO_BAI="1" EMPRESA_BAI="2" DESCRICAO_BAI="DESUSO" />
        <ROW CODIGO_BAI="2" EMPRESA_BAI="2" DESCRICAO_BAI="DOA�AO" />
        <ROW CODIGO_BAI="3" EMPRESA_BAI="2" DESCRICAO_BAI="VENDA" />
        <ROW CODIGO_BAI="4" EMPRESA_BAI="2" DESCRICAO_BAI="VEICULO SINISTRO PERDA TOTAL" CHK_DESM_BAI="N" />
        <ROW CODIGO_BAI="5" EMPRESA_BAI="2" DESCRICAO_BAI="FURTO/ROUBO" CHK_DESM_BAI="N" />
        <ROW CODIGO_BAI="6" EMPRESA_BAI="2" DESCRICAO_BAI="SUCATA" CHK_DESM_BAI="N" />
        <ROW CODIGO_BAI="7" EMPRESA_BAI="2" DESCRICAO_BAI="TRANSFER�NCIA DE CONTA CONTABIL" CHK_DESM_BAI="N" />
        <ROW CODIGO_BAI="8" EMPRESA_BAI="2" DESCRICAO_BAI="BAIXA PARA CONSUMO" CHK_DESM_BAI="N" />
    </ROWDATA>
</DATAPACKET>
```

Eu queria printar os valores das tags `ROW`. Há uma forma de passar por `ROWDATA` e chegar nas tags filhas `ROW`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Quando você itera diretamente pelo elemento (`for row in root`), ele só pega os filhos diretos do mesmo, por isso o resultado foi apenas `METADATA` e `ROWDATA`

Para procurar tags descendentes independente do nível, uma alternativa é passar o nome da tag para [`iter`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/xml.etree.elementtree.html#xml.etree.ElementTree.Element.iter):

```py
import xml.etree.ElementTree as ET

tree = ET.parse('arquivo.xml')
root = tree.getroot()
for row in root.iter('ROW'): # <--- vai procurar somente por ROW
    print(row.tag, row.attrib)
```

O detalhe é que assim ele procura por tags `ROW` em todo o documento. Por exemplo, se tivesse um `ROW` dentro de `METADATA`, ele também seria retornado.
Mas se quiser somente aquelas que estão dentro de `ROWDATA`, outra alternativa é usar [`iterfind`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/xml.etree.elementtree.html#xml.etree.ElementTree.Element.iterfind) e especificar as tags que você quer:

```py
for row in root.iterfind('./ROWDATA/ROW'):
    print(row.tag, row.attrib)
```

Note que `iterfind` usa a sintaxe de [XPath](https://docs.python.org/3/library/xml.etree.elementtree.html#elementtree-xpath). No caso, eu usei o caminho completo, assim ele só pega as tags `ROW` que estiverem dentro de `ROWDATA`, que por sua vez estão logo abaixo do root. Consulte a [documentação](https://docs.python.org/3/library/xml.etree.elementtree.html#supported-xpath-syntax) para saber todas as opções de busca disponíveis.

Comment: Muito obrigado!! Obtive um resultado ainda melhor com essa mudança no código

Answer (score -1):

Mudei um pouco o meu código adicionando apenas uma váriavel chamada filtro = '*'
e passando a mesma como parâmetro  da função iter no laço que percorre o XML, ficando assim:

```
import xml.etree.ElementTree as ET

tree = ET.parse('work.xml')
root = tree.getroot()

filtro = '*'

for row in root.iter(filtro): 
    print(row.tag, row.attrib)
```

Comment: Amigo, essa resposta resolve o problema? Ou seria uma edição à pergunta que tu fizeste?

Comment: @LeonardoAlvesMachado Resolveu o problema